# Suggested edit rejected, looking for enlightment

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I happened to stumble upon a bad formatting, no trying, typical "why is my code not working" type of question, it had a not-so-clear title and body, so I thought that maybe an edit would be suficient to make the question a bit clearer. My suggested edit was rejected under the following cause:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability

I wanted to know if by editing the title and/or body like I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11689147), how would it harm the question's readability, does it make it easier to find? I think so, but maybe I'm not looking at this from the right perspective.

Comment: I probably have rejected it because of the excess indentation and didn't bother to improve it since it was a bad question anyway..

Comment: Yeah Tunaki pointed it out. I guess I didn't remember the code formatting had already been fixed while I was editing @Floern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I cannot speak for the reviewers but your edit was probably rejected because of the formatting of the code.

You added a lot of white-spaces before each line, which makes it harder to read: each line is pushed further to the right and thus adding more scrolling to read the entire lines. From the reviewers perspective, this is what it looked like after your edit:

[image]

I personally wouldn't have rejected it: your edit fixed the title and the wording of the question. Rather, I would have improved it by removing all those added white-spaces.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that, I did forget to mention that the code was already formatted by another user, maybe I unconsciously "re" formatted it. I was more interested in the actual text of the question/title. Your answer makes sense. I should've paid attention to the output.

Comment: That's exactly it. @JustDoIt It's good that you removed the bold formatting and generally made sentences from the gibberish in the title and body. The problem is that even those correct changes don't really make it easier to understand the question. My advice: don't waste time polishing a turd. If the question is good, then it's perfectly fine to make it better.